# Why does this website horizontally scroll on webkit?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**[Website Link](http://mylingo.co/?ap=0&ep=0)**

**[Screen Capture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbhax352r9blgux/scroll_issue.mp4?dl=0)**

I'm testing this in Safari and Chrome on the latest version of OSX. It seems to be confined to `web-kit` as other people have told me there is no horizontal `scroll` in `IE`.

I attempted to fix the issue with the following **CSS**:

```
/* For the "inset" look only */
html {
    overflow: auto;
}

body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body:hover {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
} 

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}

body {
 //   overflow-x: hidden;
   font-family: "Roboto Slab","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;

    //position: relative;
//left: 15px;
//-ms-scroll-limit: 0 0 0 0;
//-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

It works except for the fact that **vertical** scroll no longer works on mobile touch devices. Probably because of this:

```
body:hover {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

I'm at a total loss here. What is the root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use overflow-x property for body tag

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[overflow-x property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms530826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

*or*

Try adding `Width : 100%` property to your **GET STARTED NOW** DIV in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of as in image below...

[image]

you can solve this by adding `class="container"` as you are using bootstrap so the row class should have a parent class container and also assign `width:100%` to it.

[image]

Comment: Oh. My. God. I forgot to add a class="container".... I spent at least 7 hours on this! Thanks man :)